# Why can't I read this csv file into R?

Tags: r, csv

To the command

```
read.csv("C:\Documents and Settings\Felhasználó\Asztal\aktuális\vizsga_lekeres.csv")
```

I received the following error message:

> Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning messages:
>
> 1: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in a character string
>
> 2: '\F' is an unrecognized escape in a character string
>
> 3: '\A' is an unrecognized escape in a character string
>
> 4: unrecognized escapes removed from "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Felhasználó\Asztal\aktuális\vizsga_lekeres.csv"
>
> 5: In file(file, "r") :   cannot open file 'C:Documents and
>   SettingsFelhasznĂˇlĂłAsztalktuĂˇlisizsga_lekeres.csv': Invalid
>   argument

What does "unrecognized escape" mean? How to fix it so that I can read this csv file correctly into R?

Comment: It means "\" should be "\\"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
read.csv("C:/Documents and Settings/Felhasználó/Asztal/aktuális/vizsga_lekeres.csv")
```

Comment: Maybe also tell them what the problem is, since they asked. *What does "unrecognized escape" mean?*

Comment: These 2 links should help you [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) and [link](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants)

Comment: I switched the direction of the slashes and it now worked. Thanks very much!

Comment: Accept the answer if that serves your purpose